# Merging the output of two related SQL queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, I have two queries from two tables.

The first table, 'Values1', have two columns: 'index1' and 'value1'. The second table, 'Values2' have columns 'index2' and 'value2'.

I want a query that for a pair of index values 'd1' and 'd2' can output all the 'index1' and 'value1' rows with a corresponding index1 between 'd1' and 'd2', as well as the number of rows in 'Values2' table that have 'index2' values between 'd1' and the 'value1' given as result of the first query, and I want the second query to loop over results of the first one. So if the first table is:

```
index1:value1
10:'A'
20:'B'
30:'C'
40:'D'
50:'E'
```

And the second table is:

```
index2:value2
0:'F'
5:'G'
15:'H'
25:'I'
35:'J'
```

the query for d1=18 and d2=32, will result in:

```
20,B,3
30,C,4
```

How can I combine the two queries to produce this kind of result?

Comment: So you want to count the number of rows in `Values2` where `index2` is between `18` and `'B'`? How does that make sense?

Comment: Why does this need to be a single query? It feels like you have one query that can return any number of rows, and another that only returns two, and they have no relation to each other. Consider what happens if there was a `25:'Q'` in the first table, what happens then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
select t1.index1, t1.value1, count(*)
from t1 join
     t2
     on t2.value2 between @d1 and t1.value1
where t1.value1 between @d1 and @d2
group by t1.index1, t1.value1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select  *
From    (
        Select  index1 as [index],value1 as value
        From    ( Values (10,'A'),(20,'B'),(30,'C'),(40,'D'),(50,'E'))as Temp(index1,value1)

        Union
        Select  index2 as [index],value2 as value
        From    ( Values (0,'F'),(5,'G'),(15,'H'),(25,'I'),(35,'J')) as Temp(index2,value2)
        ) D1
Where   D1.[index] between 18 and 32
order by [index]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear. To get the `values1` records is simple:

```
select * from values1 where index1 between @d1 and @d2;
```

As to the second part: You want to count records in table `values2` and contradicting your explanation it seems you simply want to count records where `index2 <= index1`.

```
select count(*) from values2 where index2 <= @index1
```

The two combined:

```
select
  index1,
  value1,
  (select count(*) from values2 v2 where v2.index2 <= v1.index1) as cnt
from values1 v1
where index1 between @d1 and @d2;
```